# Why is my factorization of this exercise wrong?

Tags: factoring

I have an exercise of factoring:

$7pqy^2 - 5y^2 - 5x^2 + 7pqx^2$, i must factor it.

I made this:

$7pqx^2 + 7pqy^2 -5x^2 - 5y^2$

= $-7pq(-x^2 - y^2) +5(-x^2 - y^2)$

= $(-x^2 - y^2)(5 - 7pq)$

= $(-x -y)(-x +y)(5-7pq)$

But the correct result should be:

$(x^2 +y^2)(-5 +7pq)$, that is not equal nor equivalent.

I also arrive at this result, factoring by $7pq$ instead of $-7pq$

So I do not want to know how to get to the result, but to know what I'm wrong about doing in this way.

Comment: $-x^2-y^2=-(x^2+y^2) \ne (-x-y)(-x+y)\,$.

Comment: dxiv, why is different ? what is that property ?

Comment: Just expand the RHS and you'll get $\,x^2 - y^2\,$, which is not what you have on the LHS.

Comment: oh yep, thanks dxiv

Comment: $ (-x-y)(-x+y) = x^2 - y^2$.  It does not equal $-x^2 - y^2$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You went wrong in the following step:

$$-x^2-y^2=-(x^2+y^2)\ne(-x-y)(-x+y)$$

Comment: This answer is not useful, I guess, that is why someone needed to downvote it.

Answer (score 2):

In your last step, you ***incorrectly*** treated $(-x^2 - y^2)$ as difference of squares.

Difference of squares would apply if you had $(x^2 - y^2)$ as a factor, but you don't.  What you have as a factor is $(-x^2 - y^2) = -(x^2 + y^2)$.

$$(-x^2 - y^2)(5 - 7pq) = -(x^2 + y^2)(5-7pq) = (x^2 + y^2)(7pq - 5)$$